# VHDL - Quartus II modsim

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm starting to write a VGA controller for a DE0 board. I have a model which compiles and loads onto the DE0 board. Also it displays the test message. The problem I am having is I cannot simulate my controller using Quartus II modsim. When I run the simulation I cannot start the VGA file. The little plus icon is missing from the file. A picture and the models file I am using are below:

[image]

vga model

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY VGA is 
PORT (clk                       :   IN   std_logic; -- demo had 2 bit vector
        rst                     :   IN   std_logic:='1';
        vga_hs, vga_vs          :   OUT std_logic;
        vga_r, vga_g, vga_b :   OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0));
END ENTITY VGA;

ARCHITECTURE A1 OF VGA IS
SIGNAL clk25    :   std_logic; -- clk25 signal
BEGIN
SYNC1    :  ENTITY work.sync(A1)
            PORT MAP (clk25, vga_hs, vga_vs, vga_r, vga_g, vga_b);
CLK_25 :    ENTITY work.CLK25(behav)
            PORT MAP (clk, rst, clk25);
END ARCHITECTURE A1;
```

Sync model

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY SYNC IS
GENERIC (
h_res               :   integer:= 640 ;     -- horizontal screen resolution
h_fp                :  integer:= 16 ;   -- horizontal front porch
h_bp                :   integer:= 48 ;     -- horizontal back porch
h_sync          :   integer:= 96 ;  -- horizontal sync pulse duration
h_sync_pol      :   std_logic:='0';     -- horizontal sync pulse state
v_res               :   integer:= 480 ; -- vertical screen resolution
v_fp                :   integer:= 10 ;     -- vertical front porch
v_bp                :   integer:= 33 ;      -- vertical back porch
v_sync          :  integer:= 2;    -- vertical sync pulse duration
v_sync_pol      :   std_logic:='0'    -- vertical sync pulse state
);
PORT(
clk                             :   IN      std_logic;
h_sync_pulse, v_sync_pulse  :   OUT     std_logic;
r, g, b                         :   OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0)
);
END ENTITY SYNC;

ARCHITECTURE A1 OF SYNC IS
 CONSTANT h_size  : integer := (h_res + h_fp + h_bp + h_sync); -- total horizontal vector
 CONSTANT v_size  : integer := (v_res + v_fp + v_bp + v_sync); -- total vertical vector
 SIGNAL h_pos       : integer RANGE 0 TO h_size := 0; -- total horizontal vector
 SIGNAL v_pos      : integer RANGE 0 TO h_size := 0; -- total vertical vector
BEGIN
TIMING :PROCESS(clk, h_pos, v_pos) IS
BEGIN
    IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
        IF (h_pos <= 480 or v_pos <= 285)  THEN -- middle of the screen is pic res/2 + (FP + sync + BP)
            r <= (OTHERS => '1');
            g <= (OTHERS => '1');
            b <= (OTHERS => '1');
        ELSE
            r <= (OTHERS => '0');
            g <= (OTHERS => '0');
            b <= (OTHERS => '0');   

        END IF;
                    IF (h_pos <= 480 or v_pos <= 285)  THEN -- middle of the screen is pic res/2 + (FP + sync + BP)
            r <= (OTHERS => '1');
            g <= (OTHERS => '1');
            b <= (OTHERS => '1');
        ELSE
            r <= (OTHERS => '0');
            g <= (OTHERS => '0');
            b <= (OTHERS => '0');   
        END IF;
        IF (h_pos < h_size) THEN
                h_pos <= h_pos + 1;
            ELSE
                h_pos <= 0;
            IF (v_pos < v_size) THEN
                    v_pos <= v_pos + 1;
                ELSE
                    v_pos <= 0; --< edit was v_pos <= v_pos
            END IF;
        END IF;

        IF (h_pos > h_fp and h_pos < h_fp + h_sync ) THEN -- H_POS between end of FP and the end of H_SYNC
            h_sync_pulse <= h_sync_pol;                       -- H_SYNC needs to stay high during display
        ELSE
            h_sync_pulse <= '1';
        END IF; 

        IF (v_pos > v_fp and v_pos < v_fp + v_sync ) THEN    --V_POS between end of FP and the end of V_SYNC
            v_sync_pulse <= v_sync_pol;                          -- V_SYNC needs to stay high during display
        ELSE
            v_sync_pulse <= '1';
        END IF;

        IF ((h_pos > 0 and h_pos < h_fp + h_bp + h_sync) or (v_pos > 0 and v_pos < v_fp + v_bp + v_sync )) THEN --During all of SYNC i.e FP + SYNC + BP colour signals stay low
            r <= (OTHERS => '0');
            g <= (OTHERS => '0');
            b <= (OTHERS => '0');
        END IF;         
    END IF;
END PROCESS TIMING; 
END ARCHITECTURE A1;
```

The design units after compilation do not show the architectures for either the vga.vhd or the sync.vhd files

[image]

Comment: Where's the testbench?

Comment: To save time I have not written a test bench as yet. I wanted to start by seeing if I could get it to open in mod sim then manually change some input values

Comment: Double check that you are compiling the correct files, since when compiling the file with `vga` (vga.vhd), it should result in both entity and architectures in the ModelSim work library.

Comment: Checked. I have 2 sub-subcomponents "sync" and "clk25" compiled into my model "vga" which only has a single architecture. After compilation I still just have the vga entity showing in modish but with no architecture with it.

Comment: Sounds pretty odd if you are **sure** the right file is compiled, and not an old copy.

Comment: Thats why I asked.....

Comment: I get exactly the same issue for another model that works with a different display size.

Comment: You don't give any code for clk25, so I commented out that instance. Apart from that, it all worked fine on both Modelsim and Quartus. Have you tried quitting Modelsim and Quartus, deleting all generated files (libraries, project files etc) and starting again?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, an the same result, made new project with the same files, tried commenting out the clk25 component like you said you did and still the same thing. Did you just copy and paste the model with no edits apart from removing clk25 and changing the port maps to suit?